# tail -n1 sometimes return last 2 lines

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to create a bash script that read the last entry of a file that is constantly written to. 
For example:

```
while true
do
  echo $`date +%s` >> output.txt
done
```

However, `tail -n1 output.txt` sometimes return two lines instead of one. For example

```
tail -n1 output.txt 
$1582329371
$1582329371
```

What would be the possible cause for this?

Comment: Maybe the file was being appended while tail was running. So after it found the last newline, another line was written to the file, and then `tail` printed from that newline to the end.

Comment: That makes sense. What would be the usual way to handle this? Do I need to do another tail to get the real last value?

Comment: You could put it in a variable and then use a parameter expansion operator to get everything from the last newline.

Comment: There are other problems you could run into, you might read a partial line.

Comment: This can only happens, if tail stores fiel pointers indead of lines as optimization and if possible. If I'm true, `tail -n1 <output.txt` may help. A second try is `tail -n1 output.txt | tail -n1`. The calculation by the second `tail` is ony l possible, if the first tail finished.

Comment: If you read fast enough, you will end up reading all lines in the file, as they are being written to it.  So how is that different from `tail -f FILE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used what Wiimm suggested tail -n1 output.txt | tail -n1 to solve the issue. Thanks